# What shall I return in a PDO Object to produce reliable code?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I wrote a new database class using PDO. I' struggling with a problem though. I usually return an object, so I can work with it. So when a query failed, I simply return `$this`. I have a method called `wasSuccessful()` that I use to make sure the query didn't fail.

```
$result = $database->query(...);
if ($result->wasSuccessful()) {
  // do code
}
```

However, what do I do, when the method returns `false`? For example:

```
...
if (!$this->tableExists($table)) return false;
```

When this happens, PDO tells me that I can't run functions on a boolean value. How do I tackle this in the best possible way?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: You [throw exceptions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) instead of returning false.

Comment: Assuming your second piece of code is part of your database class, and given what you stated before, logic would dictate to `return $this;` instead of `return false;` and use `...->wasSuccessful()` to check success or failure. On the other hand, checking a boolean is not difficult. However, one method cannot use both return mechanisms, because then you wouldn't know how to check it. That said, exceptions are nice too.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than relying on the return values of functions, you should use exceptions. Something like this simple example should give you the idea:

In your class:

```
class MyClass {
    public function query($sql, ...$params) {
        if (!$this->tableExists($table)) {
            throw new \Exception("the table doesn't exist");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your code:

```
try {
    $result = $database->query(...);
    // do stuff with $result, knowing it's ok
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo "here's our error handling routine";
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

In more complex projects it might be desirable to create your own exception classes. As well, you can use `try`/`catch` within your class, and `throw` exceptions from PDO to the higher-level code. For example:

```
class MyClass {
    public function query($sql, ...$params) {
        if (!$this->tableExists($table)) {
            throw new \Exception("the table doesn't exist");
            return false;
        }
        try {
            //do something with the PDO object that might throw an exception
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            // just take this existing exception and throw it to the next catch block
            throw $e;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will implement this! Didn't check for answers lately so please don't think your effort wasn't appreciated!